# Webpack output is reversed

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, config

I wanted to extract two scss files to separate css files.

The styles are compiling properly but to the wrong files.

My files and tree structure are below.

**style.scss**

```
body{background:red}
```

**hero.scss**

```
body{background:green}
```

**css.js**

```
import styles from '../sass/style.scss'
```

**hero.js**

```
import hero from '../sass/hero.scss'
```

**webpack.config.js**

http://cssdeck.com/labs/83ywcysv

The ouput is:

**style.css**

```
body{background:green}
```

**hero.css**

```
body{background:red}
```

Is there something I'm missing in the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have two different css files in the output, you need to have two different rules to tell webpack which file to use.
Create two ExtractTextPlugin instances and use them in the rules.

Something like this

http://cssdeck.com/labs/zrrjm1kw